# Default value for Date and Time column rounds up to next hour

Tags: 2013, custom-list, date-time

Have a list with column type of Date and Time call `Event Date`
We have the default value for this `Event Date` field of `Today's Date`.

When users add a new item, if it is 10:02 AM, the value for `Event Date` is 11 AM.
We'd like the default value for `Event Date` to go to 10:02 AM.

Anyway to do this?
jQuery?

Comment: Check Site-Settings regional/language settings, it doesn't round up but uses a different timezone

Comment: use =NOW() in Default value >> Calculated Value instead of just selecting "Today's Date"...that did the trick.